# Using "THIS" inside function

Tags: javascript

How can I use "this" in this case?
I got an error.. The page can't set display at null or undefined.

```
<button onclick="myFunction(this)">

<script>
function myFunction() {

this.style.display='none';

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [func.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to bind a context for that function invocation (otherwise in your case it will be pointing the the global object (window)  ):

```
myFunction.call(this);
```

or with `myFunction(this)`

You should do:

```
function myFunction(elm) {
   elm.style.display='none';
}
```

Comment: `"since the function gets invoked from global scope"` is incorrect. The function is invoked by the element's click handler and is therefore called from function scope, and scope is entirely irrelevant to how *this* is set. It is set **only** by how a function is called, or with *bind*. In the function, *this* is the global object because it was not set to any value by the call.

Answer (score 0):

An even better idea is to register the `click` event using `addEventListener` instead of with `onclick` inline in the HTML:

```
var theButton = document.getElementById("theButton");
theButton.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var originalElement = e.srcElement || e.originalTarget;
    originalElement.style.display = 'none';
});
```

Of course, you'll need to either give the button the same `id` I did -- `theButton` -- or otherwise retrieve it, but this is a much more flexible and modern way to handle the event.

Comment: A good point, of course. One possible workaround is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

Comment: Obviously, I'd prefer to use a modern library, but I'd rather see just about anything other than event attributes in the HTML.